# How to reference 2 different tables with a foreign key of the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the code for the two different tables containing the column 'clientID'

```
CREATE TABLE IndividualClient (
    clientID varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

select * from IndividualClient;

CREATE TABLE CorporateClient (
    clientID varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    businessRegNumber int(30) NOT NULL
);

select * from CorporateClient;
```

and this is the code i have a foreign key on:

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
    Project_ID varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    registrationDate date NOT NULL,
    projectTitle varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    clientID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    foreign key (clientID) references IndividualClient (clientID),
    foreign key (clientID) references CorporateClient (clientID)

);

select * from project;
```

what I want is that the clientID column on 'projects' table can reference to either the clientID from individualClient or corporateClient

is this possible?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are really using

Comment: I don't think it is possible in any DBMS. Foreign Key always references a single tab;e only.

Comment: This is probably will not happen. A simple thought is that how to make sure the clientID from individual table will not conflict or overlap with the clientID from the corporation table ?  Probably you have to redesign your database by making a new table called "client" to combine the two tables of individual and coporation.

Comment: I see, in case I make another table called 'client', how can I combine two primary keys from individualClient and corporateClient into that table?

Answer (score 0):

There will be Id conflict, and of course you can handle it by checking ID availability every time you insert but think about making one main table with two tables with columns dependant of type of client.

```
Client
------
Id
SomeCommonClientProperties

IndividualClient
----------------
ClientId
FirstName
LastName
Address
PhoneNumber

CorporateClient
---------------
ClientId
Name
Address
PhoneNumber
BusinessRegNumber
```

That way you will reference to table Client and unique ClientId would guide you to proper individual/corporate table.

PS. I would also consider separate tables for Address and ContactData referencing to Client

Comment: so the ID from the new Client table is unique, and I just have to add another common property between Client - Individual/Corporate client such as name?

Comment: you dont have to but u might. you can Add column "ClientType" that way you will always know which table to look for all client data. You won't have to check in both of them.